# How to quickly survey a table column (count of distinct values)

Tags: sql-server, r

A power user often uses SQL and other languages (e.g., R).
In exploring a table (e.g., with disease data), there may be a column Severity with values Mild, Moderate, Severe.

In many languages (e.g., R) a user can write

```
table(diseasedata$severity)
```

and see a quick table how many rows (count of rows) there are for each severity.

```
mild      20321
moderate  3512
severe    35135
```

A user with no rights to write own functions and just plain tsql rights, is there a smart TSQL command similar to table(column) to produce a nice overview of the column?

I am looking for something more advanced and shorter than 'select severity, count(*) from tbl group by severity' !

Comment: assume 20 tables, each with 30 columns. By short - I mean not repeating column name twice.  The point is, what are advanced TSQL commands for an R user used to work with data.frame() and many quick statistical functions in R. The tables are too large to put into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a code snippet with some dynamic SQL where you only need to change the assignment of a couple of variables to query different tables and different fields.

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'diseasedata'
declare @FieldName sysname = 'severity'

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'select '+quotename(@FieldName)+', count(*) as C
            from '+quotename(@TableName)+'
            group by '+quotename(@FieldName)
exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: interesting solution. MS should, however, include some better functions if it wants to be a BigData db engine provider. In the era of BigData, analysts simply want much more than SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Without creating your own functions / views... then no, this is as terse as out-of-the-box Sql gets:

```
select severity, count(*) from tbl group by severity
```

Maybe I'm just used to Sql, but that seems pretty short and sweet to me...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to critical but if by "more advanced" you mean "more complicated", why would you want more complicated code - to get you the same answer (as a group by)? I'm sure that not it.

Assuming you mean you need only approximate distibutions, and on very large dataset columns (i.e. >= billions of rows) where there aren't any good indexes. An alternative I have used is to try to find some columns statistics on that table, using the command DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx). That can very fast if you're lucky, returning a distribution for over 100,000,000,000 rows in few milli-seconds. But, they will only be approximate and can be out of date, or if your unlucky - not there at all.

Comment: Absolutely agree with M Fredrickson - the SQL is probably still shorter than the description in plain English.